# Where is gulp-front-matter putting my front matter?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm trying to use this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-front-matter) to both strip some [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) from a markdown file and then *give me access to the markdown it stripped*. Which brings me to my question (code from module page):

```
var frontMatter = require('gulp-front-matter');

gulp.task('blog-posts', function() {
    gulp.src('./posts/*.md')
        .pipe(frontMatter({          // optional configuration 
            property: 'frontMatter', // property added to file object  
            remove: true // should we remove front-matter header? 
        }))
        .pipe(…); 
    });
```

So there's that comment `// property added to the file object`. What does that mean? How can I get to the front matter data? Perhaps more accurate, how do I access the 'file' object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. The module is assuming people will use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data) which allows access to the `file` object. I appear to have the answer to my question: gulp-data wants to be the standard way for "attaching data to the file object for other plugins to consume," which is apparently something gulp doesn't have a standard for just now.

Working code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var markdown = require('gulp-markdown');
var frontMatter = require('gulp-front-matter');
var data = require('gulp-data');

markdown.marked.setOptions({
    gfm: false
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('*.md')
        .pipe(frontMatter({ 
            property: 'pig',
            remove: true 
        }))
        .pipe(data(function(file) {
            console.log(file.pig.layout);
        }))
        .pipe(markdown({tables: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

});